# Cordova/Ionic - Set Portrait Only Mode for Mobiles and allow Orientation in Tablets

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-orientation, device-orientation

How do we set Mobile phones to Portrait only and allow tablets to switch between portrait and landscape?

I am using Ionic/Cordova.

Currently I have configured to set the app to be in portrait mode in config.xml using the following property

```
 <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Comment: can you specify the platforms you are targeting? android only? iphone? ipads?

Answer (score 8):

You could use [isTablet plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-istablet) in conjunction with [screen orientation plugin](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation), something like:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.isTablet){
        screen.unlockOrientation();
    }else{
        screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
    } 
  });
})
```

Comment: The ionic platform now has platform.is('tablet') built in. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#is